# How do I check if a constraint exists on Firebird?

Tags: firebird

I'm about to publish a script which will update a lot of Firebird databases all at once. Some will not have this constraint, so I would like to check for the existence of a constraint before I try to drop it.

```
ALTER TABLE PROCESS_CATEGORY DROP CONSTRAINT INTEG_669;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can query `RDB$RELATION_CONSTRAINTS` table, if you know the name of the constraint. 
Something like this:

```
set term ^;
execute block as
begin
    if (exists(
        select 0 from rdb$relation_constraints
        where rdb$constraint_name = 'INTEG_669'
    )) then
        execute statement 'alter table process_category drop constraint INTEG_669';
end
^
set term ;^
```

Used `execute statement` because `alter table` not allowed inside the block and `if` statement not allowed outside.

Comment: I'll upvote this, but you should probably provide the columns in `RDB$RELATION_CONSTRAINTS` that would be needed along with a sample query.